# Edit value for core data key for certain id

Tags: swift, entity

I have a Core data entity that is made of id and detailText. The idea is that my textfield stores it's content alongside certain id that is a timestamp in my case. Now when the user stores the detailText for the first time it works as it should, but if the user edits the detailText for the specific id, I want to remove the old detailText and put the new detailText. 
Basically I need help with writing the query below in Swift/Core data.

```
 UPDATE myEntity SET detailText = theNewDetailText WHERE ID = myID;
```

These are my current save and replace function, I use predicate to find select my id but I'm having trouble updating the corresponding detailText field for the certain ID.

```
 func saveTextFromTextFieldToCoreData(textToSave: String){

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entityDescription =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("GoalDetail", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let thingToSaveToCD = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


    print("received text to store and it's \(textToSave)")

    if  entityIsEmpty("GoalDetail") == true {
        thingToSaveToCD.setValue(data.timeStamp, forKey: "id")
        thingToSaveToCD.setValue(textToSave, forKey: "detailText")
        print("succesfully saved \(data.timeStamp) and \(textToSave)")

    } else {

        replaceTheValueFromCoreData()

    }
}

func replaceTheValueFromCoreData(){

    print("i have entered the delete core data item")
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "GoalDetail")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", data.timeStamp)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    //let entityDescription =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("GoalDetail", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    //let thingToSaveToCD = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    do{
        let goal = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        try managedContext.save()
    }

    catch{
        //error
    }
```

I've been through google and stack overflow but so far haven't managed to execute this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it

```
     func saveTextFromTextFieldToCoreData(textToSave: String){

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entityDescription =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("GoalDetail", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let thingToSaveToCD = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    //clumsy named entity is empty returns if there is already
    // an ID / data.timeStamp in that entity so that I can
    // either save or replace the data
    print("received text to store and it's \(textToSave)")

    if  entityIsEmpty("GoalDetail") == true {
        thingToSaveToCD.setValue(data.timeStamp, forKey: "id")
        thingToSaveToCD.setValue(textToSave, forKey: "detailText")
        print("succesfully saved \(data.timeStamp) and \(textToSave)")

    } else {
        replaceTheValueFromCoreData()
        print("ovo tribq prominiti")

    }

}



 func replaceTheValueFromCoreData(){

    print("i have entered the delete core data item")
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "GoalDetail")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", self.data.timeStamp)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
    if let fetchResults = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
        if fetchResults.count != 0{

            var managedObject = fetchResults[0]
            managedObject.setValue(self.trextViewForGoal.text, forKey: "detailText")

            try managedContext.save()
        }
        }}

        catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}
```